# SQL query involving inner join and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a MySQL query that will optimize my Rails 3 application.

I have 2 tables: segments and custom properties.

Table defs are:

segments
- name
- organization_id
- ancestry
- ancestry_depth

custom_properties
- name
- label
- value
- segment_id

Segments are tree-like structures, thus the ancestry columns.  e.g. Segment 3 is a child of Segment 2 is a child of Segment 1.  Each of those segments will have the same custom properties, however, the values could come from an inherited segment (a segment up the tree) instead of from the segment itself.  If a value of a particular property is inherited from a segment up the tree, then its value is set to null.

My goal is to retrieve custom properties for a particular segment, in a single SQL statement, while taking into consideration the depth of the segment since depth determines the priority order of the values that I need.

The current query I have is very close, it returns the correct number of properties for a particular segment, however, with that group by statement I always get the property with the lowest ID, but what I really need is the property with the highest depth.  If I take out the group by then I get duplicate properties, 1 from each segment listed in the "IN".  But again, I only need property from the highest depth.

```
SELECT custom_properties.name, 
       custom_properties.value, 
       segments.ancestry_depth 
FROM   custom_properties 
       INNER JOIN segments 
         ON custom_properties.object_id = segments.id 
WHERE  custom_properties.object_type = 'Segment' 
       AND custom_properties.object_id IN ( 86770, 86637, 40667, 180 ) 
       AND custom_properties.value IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY custom_properties.name 
ORDER  BY custom_properties.name, 
          segments.ancestry_depth DESC
```

I hope this makes sense.  I appreciate any help and/or direction.

Thank you!

Louis

Comment: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm is your friend.

Comment: mysql, sql server, oracle, etc.?

Comment: Is the highest depth the one with the lowest numeric value (ie. is 1 "higher" than 2)?

Comment: nope, highest depth is highest number.  2 is higher than 1

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `DESC` keyword from the `ORDER BY` clause.

EDIT:

Try the following:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM   (SELECT custom_properties.name, 
               custom_properties.value, 
               segments.ancestry_depth 
        FROM   custom_properties 
               INNER JOIN segments 
                 ON custom_properties.object_id = segments.id 
        WHERE  custom_properties.object_type = 'Segment' 
               AND custom_properties.object_id IN ( 86770, 86637, 40667, 180 ) 
               AND custom_properties.value IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER  BY custom_properties.name, 
                  segments.ancestry_depth DESC) v
GROUP  BY name
```

Comment: `Order by` with `group by` does not work because result are already grouped when sorting start to work.

Comment: right, order by isn't doing anything.  could certainly be removed.

Comment: Mark, my man, you nailed it!  I owe you a beer.  Now the question is how does this work???

Thank you very much!

Comment: If only I knew where to collect it from! ORDER BY in a main query is only applied after the group (silly me) - before the group, it is ordered by values on indexes. However, ORDERing in the subquery is applied before grouping in the main query - which is why it works.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Again, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Maby this wil work:

```
SELECT c.name, c.VALUE, s1.ancestry_depth, s2.ancestry_depth as depth
FROM custom_properties as c
JOIN segments s1 ON c.object_id = s1.id
LEFT JOIN segments s2 ON c.object_id = s2.id AND s2.ancestry_depth > s1.ancestry_depth
WHERE  c.object_type = 'Segment' 
AND c.object_id IN ( 86770, 86637, 40667, 180 ) 
AND c.VALUE IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY c.name 
HAVING ISNULL(depth)
ORDER  BY c.name, s1.ancestry_depth DESC
```

**edit:** I misunderstood you and was selecting properties with biggest depth but i should select segnents with biggest depth

Comment: Tried to run this, get: Unknown column 's2.ancestry_depth' in 'having clause'

Comment: I changed depth to ancestry_depth and it ran but the results are unfortunately the same as my query.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why changed depth? It's alias for s2.ancestry_depth and is important. Didn't it worked with depth ?

Comment: The query posted by Mark did the trick!  Thanks again for your help.